# Can a DataGrid column be two-way bound to a dictionary item?

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, xaml

I am working on a bound `DataGrid` that displays data from a database. I'm using Silverlight 5 if that helps. Currently all the data is stored in a `Dictionary` within the my entity object. Using the `Property[Key]` syntax for the binding path binds properly for display purposes. But the column acts like it is readonly when trying to change a column value in runtime.

```
Public Class Entity
    Public Property Attributes As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
End Class

'Sample data
Dim Entities As New List(Of Entity)
Entities.Add(New Entity With {.Attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"Name", "Joe"}, {"City", "Detroit"}}})
Entities.Add(New Entity With {.Attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"Name", "Bob"}, {"City", "Chicago"}}})
Entities.Add(New Entity With {.Attributes = New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {{"Name", "Fred"}, {"City", "Dallas"}}})
MyDataGrid1.ItemsSource = Entities

<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="12,276,12,12" Name="MyDataGrid1">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Attributes[Name], Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Attributes[City], Mode=TwoWay}" Header="City" Width="Auto" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

I tried setting a textbox up with the same binding on a single entity and everything works as intended for displaying and setting the value. This should rule out the `Dictionary` as being the issue.

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=Attributes[Name], Mode=TwoWay}" />

TextBox1.DataContext = Entities(1)
```

I also tried the `Property[Index]` path syntax on a `List`, which also works as intended.  So I guess I'm currently not understanding why the `DataGrid` isn't letting me edit the column items.

My other thought was to use a value converter for the column and pass the key as the converter parameter. But the `DataGrid` acts the same way as just binding to the `Property[Key]` and not allowing editing for that column.

```
Public Class AttributeValueConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.Convert
        Dim Attributes As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = value
        Dim Name As String = parameter
        If Attributes IsNot Nothing And Name IsNot Nothing Then
            Return Attributes(Name)
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As System.Type, parameter As Object, culture As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As Object Implements System.Windows.Data.IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ps:AttributeValueConverter x:Key="AttributeValueConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Attributes, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource AttributeValueConverter}, ConverterParameter=Name}" Header="Name" Width="Auto" />
```

Has anyone run into this type of situation or have any suggestions on how to accomplish the goal? My only thought right now is to store the column values in ordered lists and display them using an index rather than key. But I would really like to know why the key isn't working.

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but it seems to me that if you want two-way binding using the IValueConverter method, you'd need to implement ConvertBack() in order for keyed data to update back into the dictionary.

Comment: I have tried to implement the ConvertBack(), but the function is never called. I have to assume it is never called because the cell never goes into an edit state to require the ConvertBack().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm answering my own question, but I hope it will help anyone else with this issue.

In trying to solve my problem using ordered lists, I found that the `DataGridTextColumn` only allows editing when the bound property is a `String`. When the dictionaries in my example are changed to `Dictionary(Of String, String)`, the two-way binding and editing of the cell works as intended. This would also explain why the `IValueConverter` would not work because it will only return an `Object`. I still would like to deal with objects instead of strings, so I made a quick abstract of the `DataGridColumn`.

```
Public Class MyDataGridTextColumn
    Inherits DataGridColumn

    Private _Binding As Binding
    Public Property Binding As Binding
        Get
            Return Me._Binding
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Binding)
            If Me._Binding IsNot value Then
                Me._Binding = value
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Function GenerateElement(cell As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell, dataItem As Object) As System.Windows.FrameworkElement
        Dim textBlock As TextBlock = New TextBlock()
        textBlock.Margin = New Thickness(4)
        textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
        If Me.Binding IsNot Nothing Then
            textBlock.SetBinding(textBlock.TextProperty, Me.Binding)
        End If
        Return textBlock
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function GenerateEditingElement(cell As System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell, dataItem As Object) As System.Windows.FrameworkElement
        Dim textBox As TextBox = New TextBox()
        textBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch
        textBox.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent)
        If Me.Binding IsNot Nothing Then
            textBox.SetBinding(textBox.TextProperty, Me.Binding)
        End If
        Return textBox
    End Function

End Class
```

When this column class is used as the replacement for `DataGridTextColumn`, all the issues I was having are now gone. Even the `ConvertBack` function is called when using an `IValueConverter`.